# publishSubject Synchronization anomaly warning

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I was playing with RxSwift on playground and I'm confronted to a warning.
Here is the complete warning message :

```
Synchronization anomaly was detected.
- Debugging: To debug this issue you can set a breakpoint in RxSwift/RxSwift/Rx.swift:113 and observe the call stack.
Problem: This behavior is breaking the observable sequence grammar. `next (error | completed)?`
- This behavior breaks the grammar because there is overlapping between sequence events.
Observable sequence is trying to send an event before sending of previous event has finished.
- Interpretation: Two different unsynchronized threads are trying to send some event simultaneously.
This is undefined behavior because the ordering of the effects caused by these events is nondeterministic and depends on the 
operating system thread scheduler. This will result in a random behavior of your program.
- Remedy: If this is the expected behavior this message can be suppressed by adding `.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)`
or by synchronizing sequence events in some other way.
```

Here is the code on Playground.

```
import RxSwift
import Foundation

example("PublishSubject") {
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
let subject = PublishSubject<String>()


subject.onNext("")
subject.subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
    print(value)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
subject.onNext("")

subject.onNext("️")
subject.onNext("️")
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
    for index in 0...10 {
        subject.onNext("1")
    }
          subject.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance).subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
        print(value)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
    for index in 0...10 {
        subject.onNext("B")
    }
    subject.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance).subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
        print(value)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
}
```

How can I do to solve this warning problem?? thx

Comment: `import PlaygroundSupport` and add this line if required  `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`

Comment: it's not about playground, it's about Rxswift, I have this have this problem on my project also...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are sending an event on your subject while it is in the middle of processing an event. That breaks the contract that subjects must maintain.

Specifically, subjects do not have any sort of thread tracking in them so you have to do it manually. The most obvious way would be to put a Recursive Lock around your `onNext` calls so they don't overlap when being run on separate threads.

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
let subject = PublishSubject<String>()
let lock = NSRecursiveLock()

subject.onNext("")
subject.subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
    print(value)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
subject.onNext("")

subject.onNext("️")
subject.onNext("️")
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
    for index in 0...10 {
        lock.lock()
        subject.onNext("1")
        lock.unlock()
    }
    subject.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance).subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
        print(value)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
    for index in 0...10 {
        lock.lock()
        subject.onNext("B")
        lock.unlock()
    }
    subject.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance).subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
        print(value)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: wonderfull thx
I didn't know about NSRecursiveLock. you save my day

Comment: Of course, if you can avoid using the `Subject` in the first place, that would be better. Glad I could help.

Comment: you mean PublishSubject? why I shouldn't?

Comment: Avoidance of subjects makes your code cleaner, and helps ensure that these sorts of problems don't happen. That said, you might not be able to avoid using a subject in this particular case, but if you can you should. There's a more complex answer (http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx) but I had to read that answer multiple times before I started to get it and I certainly can't summarize it any better than the above.

Comment: In my case I resolved this warning by adding .observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance) to my rx binding

Comment: @jcpennypincher That's a hack for when all else fails, but be sure you know what is happening when you use that method. `.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)` routes the event to a background serial thread and then back to the main thread. It's rather more expensive than fixing the problem from first principles so use it sparingly.

Comment: I also had the similar case. Fixed by using an Observable instead of PublishSubject.